# Firebase sendPasswordResetEmail doesn't seem to work correctly with firebase-auth:9.0.2

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I am moving an Android app to the new Firebase platform from the old one. I can't seem to get sendPasswordResetEmail to work as documented for email/password authentication if given an unknown email string.

The documentation says:

> public Task sendPasswordResetEmail (String email)
>
> Triggers the Firebase Authentication backend to send a password-reset
>   email to the given email address, which must correspond to an existing
>   user of your app.
>
> Exceptions:
>
> FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException thrown if there is no user
>   corresponding to the given email address Returns Task to track
>   completion of the sending operation

Here is my pw reset method:

```
 // firebase password reset
private void requestPwReset() {
    String email = mEmailView.getText().toString();
    Log.d(TAG, "sending pw reset request for: " + email);
    try {
        Task<Void> task = mAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
        Log.d("TAG", "result: " + (task.isSuccessful() == true) ); // NEVER SUCCEEDS, EVEN WITH VALID EMAIL ADDRESS
    } catch(FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException e) {  //COMPILE ERROR HERE!
        Log.d(TAG, "exception: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Calling this method causes this compile time error (which the IDE also flags):

> LoginActivity.java:117: error: exception
>   FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException is never thrown in body of
>   corresponding try statement
>           } catch(FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException e) {

If I omit the try-catch code then the method compiles, but  the returned task never succeeds, even with known good email addresses.

The good news is that Firebase does eventually send a reset to good addresses, but I'm wondering why the sendPasswordResetEmail doesn't throw the documented exception if given an unknown user email or a successful Task when given a valid email.

I did see in the May 18 release notes that there is an iOS issue with this function.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`FirebaseAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(...)` returns a [Task](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task#public-constructor-summary).

A `Task` represents an eventual result which completes asynchronously. This is also why `task.isSuccessful()` will return `false` when you check if it has completed immediately after making the request.

What you should be doing is:

```
mAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
  .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener() {
      public void onSuccess(Void result) {
        // send email succeeded
      }
   }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
      public onFailure(Exception e)
        // something bad happened
      }
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to do this Simply use this function

```
    private void resetPassword(final String email) {
        mAuth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Reset email instructions sent to " + email, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(mActivity, email + " does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```